# How to store a custom object to user defaults in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, custom-object

I tried converting my objects to instances of NSData, putting them in an NSArray and storing the array in user defaults. I also tried putting the objects in an NSArray, converting the array to an instance of NSData and storing it in user defaults. Both ways I get the following error:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GelirObject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89dbf90"
The name of my custom object is GelirObject.`

I know that custom objects cannot be stored to user defaults directly. That's why I used NSData, but still I get this error. How can I store my objects without getting error?

Comment: I don't think you correctly serialized the object into an NSData. Can you show how you tried to do that?

Comment: It could be that you're assigning an object of type `GelirObject*` to a variable of type `NSData*`, which you then try to save to the user defaults.

Comment: I serialized this way: NSData *incomeObjectData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:incomeObject]; I already checked the post Storing data to NSUserDefaults but I couldn't understand why I got the error

Comment: @user3113020: Your object needs to implement `encodeWithCoder:` as shown in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, it's just wrong what you are doing. You shouldn't put a lot of information inside your `NSUserDefaults`. As for the issue:

```
NSData *incomeObjectData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:incomeObject];
```

Your `GelirObject` doesn't comply with the `NSCoding` protocol. That's the reason your app is screaming. Just implement the required methods `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`.